# thread.Join() вызывается раньше начала работы потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, .net-core

В начале выполняется данный кусок кода:

```
        List<Thread> listOfThreads = new List<Thread>(50);// 50 взято для примера
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
        {
            listOfThreads.Add(new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(voidForThreads)));
            ParametersForThread parameters = new ParametersForThread()
            {
                // Некоторые параметры
            };
            listOfThreads[i].Start(parameters);
        }
```

После:

```
        foreach (var thread in listOfThreads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
```

Код отрабатывает, метод, где создаётся 50 потоков, гордо возвращает null, а потом срабатывает breakPoint внутри `voidForThreads`. 50 раз подряд...

Если я правильно понимаю причину, то `thread.Join();` вызывается раньше, чем потоки начинают свою работу. Чем такой недуг можно вылечить? Или причина и вовсе в другом?

**UPD**: Вот метод `voidForThreads`:

```
    private async Task voidForThreads(object obj)
    {
        ParametersForThread parameters = (ParametersForThread)obj;

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "site");

        var getOrderRequest = new GetOrderRequest()
        {
            OrderIDArray = parameters.PackOrders,
        };


        string text = new XMLConverter().ConvertObjectToXMLString(typeof(GetOrderRequest), getOrderRequest);
        request.Content = new StringContent(text);

        var client = parameters._clientFactory.CreateClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        try
        {
            response = await client.SendAsync(request: request);
        }
        catch
        {
            // тут немного другая логика, но в блок catch в данном методе я
            // ещё ни разу не попадал - не думаю, что проблема в нём
            throw new NotImplementedException(); 
        }

        // Метод отработал верно - я проверял
        GetOrderResponse result = (GetOrderResponse)new XMLConverter().ConvertXMLStringToObject(typeof(GetOrderResponse), await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        // private GetOrderResponseOrderArray[][] ResultList - приватное поле, объявлено заранее
        ResultList[parameters.NumberInList] = new GetOrderResponseOrderArray[result.OrderArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.OrderArray.Length; i++)
        {
            // Логика немного упрощена - мне не весь массив результатов нужен, поэтому здесь
            // поштучное копирование нужных полей
            ResultList[parameters.numberInList][i] = result.OrderArray[i];
        }
    }
```

И также класс `ParametersForThread`:

```
    private class ParametersForThread
    {
        public string[] PackOrders { get; set; }
        public IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory { get; set; }
        public int NumberInList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Подскажите, а какую именно задачу вы решаете в данном коде? Запустить 50 потоков и продолжить выполнение программы, когда все отработают, верно я понял?

Comment: @aepot Да, верно. Мне нужно 50 раз осуществить вызов сторонних API. Не хотелось бы в один поток ждать 50 ответов

Comment: а зачем их в список добавлять? Может это лишнее? Может просто 50 запустить, а потом дождаться, когда все закончат? Я для того чтобы правильный ответ написать спрашиваю.

Comment: @aepot Возможно я не знаю, как к потокам без списка обратиться. Заранее их число мне неизвестно. Но если есть способ общения с потоками без списка - я только за.


Спрашивайте всё, что сочтёте нужным - я только рад буду помочь Вам помочь мне)

Comment: покажите код `voidForThreads`

Comment: Зачем такие сложности, когда давно есть async/await и не надо мучиться вручную что-то там запускать и джойнить потом.

Comment: @tym32167 Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @CrazyElf Можете пример показать? Я только начал изучать многопоточность и буду очень рад Вашей помощи

Comment: @Anatoly У вас voidForThreads уже async Task, поэтому вам надо делать не список Thread-ов, а список Task-ов. Почитайте про Task и async/await. Всё гораздо проще можно сделать, чем у вас, но для начала почитайте доки и примеры. Например вот: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Вернее, лучше в целом про Task: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: У вас должно быть что-то типа tasks.Add(Task.Run(voidForThreads)) и потом Task.WhenAll(tasks).

Comment: Асинхронный метод может вернуть управление до того, как закончится сам. Ничего удивительного, что ваши треды рапортуют о том, что отработали, хотя сама работа еще не завершена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отдельная благодарность пользователям @aepot и @CrazyElf.

Код ниже хоть и не даёт ответа на вопрос "Почему `thread.Join()` отработал раньше старта работы потоков?", - но решает мою проблему:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private GetOrderResponseOrderArray[][] ResultArray { get; set; }

    // Конструкция List<string[]> listOfPackOrders вызвана ограничениями используемых API
    public async Task MainMethod(IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory, List<string[]> listOfPackOrders)
    {
        if (_clientFactory is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_clientFactory));
        }

        if (listOfPackOrders is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(listOfPackOrders));
        }

        ResultArray = new GetOrderResponseOrderArray[listOfPackOrders.Count][];
        Task[] arrayOfTasks = new Task[listOfPackOrders.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfPackOrders.Count; i++)
        {
            ParametersForThread parameters = new ParametersForThread()
            {
                NumberInList = i,
                PackOrders = listOfPackOrders[i],
                _clientFactory = _clientFactory
            };
            arrayOfTasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => { await TaskForTaskArray(parameters); });
        }
        Task.WaitAll(arrayOfTasks);

        // Дальнейшая работа с ResultArray
    }


    private async Task TaskForTaskArray(ParametersForThread parameters)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "site");

        var getOrderTransactionsRequest = new GetOrderTransactionsRequest()
        {
            OrderIDArray = parameters.PackOrders;
        };

        string text = new XMLConverter().ConvertObjectToXMLString(typeof(GetOrderTransactionsRequest), getOrderTransactionsRequest);
        request.Content = new StringContent(text);

        var client = parameters._clientFactory.CreateClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            try
            {
                response = await client.SendAsync(request: request);
            }
            catch
            {
                // тут немного другая логика, но в блок catch в данном методе я
                // ещё ни разу не попадал - не думаю, что проблема в нём
                throw new NotImplementedException(); 
            } 

        GetOrderResponse result = (GetOrderResponse)new XMLConverter().ConvertXMLStringToObject(typeof(GetOrderResponse), await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        ResultList[parameters.NumberInList] = new GetOrderResponseOrderArray[result.OrderArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.OrderArray.Length; i++)
        {
            // Логика немного упрощена - мне не весь массив результатов нужен, поэтому здесь
            // поштучное копирование нужных полей
            ResultList[parameters.numberInList][i] = result.OrderArray[i];
        }
    }

    private class ParametersForThread
    {
        public string[] PackOrders { get; set; }
        public IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory { get; set; }
        public int NumberInList { get; set; }
    }
}
```