# Синхронизация переменных в многопоточном консольном приложении

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь писать приложение с использованием потоков, но переменная count не обновляется в рамках всех действующих потоков, ниже после кода приведён пример.

А так же random застревает на одном значении.

Я подозреваю что я что-то не записал или выбрал не очень удачный аналог рандома.

```
    public class Calculate
    {
        static object locker = new object();
        static int count = 0; 
        public static void Strike()
        {
                int[] bufer = new int[15];
                lock (locker)
                {
                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        for (int j = 1; j < bufer.Length - 1; j++)
                        {
                            bufer[j] = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                        }
                }
                Console.Write(++count+") "+bufer.ToString());
        }
        public static double Final
        {
            get 
            {
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(Strike);
                thread1.Start();
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(Strike);
                thread2.Start();
                Thread thread3 = new Thread(Strike);
                thread3.Start();
                Thread thread4 = new Thread(Strike);
                thread4.Start();
                return 99;//не обращайте внимание
            }
        }
    }
```

При запуске оно выводит 4 одинаковые записи. А хотелось бы чтобы нумерация шла как надо и числа 0 и 1 генерировались случайным образом.

"Как есть"

1) 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 246

1) 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 246

1) 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 246

1) 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 246

"Как должно быть"

1) 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 246

2) 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 334

3) 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 228

4) 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 288

Comment: `Random rnd = new Random();` он зависит от времени. А все потоки по сути сразу стартуют.

Comment: Random для генерации случайных чисел использует псевдо-случайную последовательность, зависящую от базы, а она, в свою очередь, при использовании конструктора по умолчанию, использует текущее время. У Random есть конструктор, принимающий на вход целое число, используй его, если нужно стартануть потоки одновременно и получать различные случайные значения в каждом из потоков.

Answer (score 0):

[Interlocked.Increment](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8) - гарантирует, что несколько потоков не обновляют одну переменную параллельно.

Также, раз Вы только начали использовать потоки, рекомендую обратить внимание на [Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8), лично мне очень помогло. Вот [простейший пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099825/thread-join-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)

**UPD2:**

```
    public class Calculate
    {
        private static int[][] bufer = new int[4][];
        private static async Task Strike(int number)
        {
            bufer[number] = new int[15];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int j = 0; j < bufer.Length; j++)
            {
                bufer[number][j] = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            }
        }
        public static double Final
        {
            get
            {
                Task[] taskArray = new Task[4];
                for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    int index = i; // Поверь, так лучше.
                    // Потоки стартуют с небольшим запаздыванием, и если использовать i,
                    // то рано или поздно выйдешь за пределы массива
                    taskArray[index] = Task.Run(() => Strike(index));
                }
                Task.WaitAll(taskArray);

                for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + ") " + bufer[i].ToString());
                }

                return 99;//не обращаю внимания
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Но Interlocked.Increment не гарантирует, что вывод будет в нужном порядке.

Comment: Вот кстати Interlocked.Increment(ref count) я поставил. И у меня есть повторения в нумерации и она теперь в разноброс, т.е. раньше было 4 числа в ряд, а теперь расколбас.

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен. Был невнимателен. Обновил ответ

Comment: Вы можете сделать сразу `async Task<string> Strike(int number)` и никакие доп поля с буферами не нужны.